# Looking back in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set of product sales and pricing that is sorted by product by week.  I want to create a data step that "looks back" 12 weeks from the current week and selects the maximum price for that product.  The 12 week "look back" period would then move forward as the data step progresses.

Is this possible?

Also, i'm NOT a sas coder.  Simple data steps are my speed.

I'm also a newbie here and do not know how to post data so I could use a quick pointer on how to do that and I'll update my post.

Thanks

Jeff

```
Item    Week    Units   Dollars Avg Price
Item 1  2505    14  $315    $22.50 
Item 1  2506    7   $166    $23.71 
Item 1  2507    7   $100    $14.36 
Item 1  2508    13  $387    $29.77 
Item 1  2509    11  $231    $21.00 
Item 1  2510    7   $168    $24.00 
Item 1  2511    15  $397    $26.47 
Item 1  2512    12  $222    $18.50 
Item 1  2513    14  $453    $32.36 
Item 1  2514    19  $557    $29.32 
Item 1  2515    12  $369    $30.73 
Item 1  2516    11  $272    $24.73 
Item 1  2517    15  $462    $30.80 
Item 1  2518    9   $160    $17.78 
Item 1  2519    15  $404    $26.93 
Item 1  2520    17  $382    $22.47 
Item 1  2521    4   $129    $32.25 
Item 1  2522    9   $219    $24.33 
Item 1  2523    8   $274    $34.22 
Item 1  2524    30  $685    $22.83 
Item 1  2525    25  $607    $24.28 
Item 1  2526    15  $430    $28.67 
Item 1  2527    19  $445    $23.42 
Item 1  2528    11  $295    $26.81 
Item 1  2529    14  $356    $25.43 
Item 1  2530    17  $396    $23.32 
Item 1  2531    13  $340    $26.15 
Item 1  2532    13  $329    $25.31 
Item 1  2533    8   $240    $30.00 
Item 1  2534    10  $230    $23.00 
Item 1  2535    6   $268    $44.67
```

Comment: how does 2505/2535 or other values in the column represent a week?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research on how to do this? The question as asked is rather broad and this site is not a code-on-request service.

Comment: the 2500 numbers are a designations that number weeks starting in 1970.  I get it that this isn't a place to get people to do your work for you, but the person who was running this algorithm in C is leaving the company and I am trying to see if I can do this in SAS.  I haven't really tried anything because I don't know how to basically select a range.  I am just looking for a couple of pointers on how to do it in a data step and not a full blown subroutine.  Apologies if i'm crossing the line.

Comment: There are a couple of things you can do here. 1) add a counter 1 - n; 2) look into arrays; 3) look into the retain statement.  With those under your belt it should be fairly simple.  Show us what you try and perhaps we can help

Answer (score 0):

One approach is a SQL query with a reflexive sub-select for computing sliding window lookups.

```
* The & in list input means the values are separated by two or more whitespace;

data have;
input
Item& $  Week&    Units&   Dollars&  dollar4. Avg_Price& dollar7.2;
format avg_price dollar6.2;
datalines;
Item 1  2505    14  $315    $22.50 
Item 1  2506    7   $166    $23.71 
Item 1  2507    7   $100    $14.36 
Item 1  2508    13  $387    $29.77 
Item 1  2509    11  $231    $21.00 
Item 1  2510    7   $168    $24.00 
Item 1  2511    15  $397    $26.47 
Item 1  2512    12  $222    $18.50 
Item 1  2513    14  $453    $32.36 
Item 1  2514    19  $557    $29.32 
Item 1  2515    12  $369    $30.73 
Item 1  2516    11  $272    $24.73 
Item 1  2517    15  $462    $30.80 
Item 1  2518    9   $160    $17.78 
Item 1  2519    15  $404    $26.93 
Item 1  2520    17  $382    $22.47 
Item 1  2521    4   $129    $32.25 
Item 1  2522    9   $219    $24.33 
Item 1  2523    8   $274    $34.22 
Item 1  2524    30  $685    $22.83 
Item 1  2525    25  $607    $24.28 
Item 1  2526    15  $430    $28.67 
Item 1  2527    19  $445    $23.42 
Item 1  2528    11  $295    $26.81 
Item 1  2529    14  $356    $25.43 
Item 1  2530    17  $396    $23.32 
Item 1  2531    13  $340    $26.15 
Item 1  2532    13  $329    $25.31 
Item 1  2533    8   $240    $30.00 
Item 1  2534    10  $230    $23.00 
Item 1  2535    6   $268    $44.67 
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select
    outer.*,
    (select max(inner.avg_price) from have as inner
     where inner.week between outer.week-12 and outer.week-1
       and outer.item = inner.item
    ) as item_max_avg_price_12wk_prior format=dollar6.2
  from
    have as outer
  order by
    week
  ;
```

A second approach is serial processing of the data and using a ring (or circular) array to store past values.  A ring array reference uses a modulus of index to ensure circularity.  The max is computed from the ring array and the array is reset when a new item appears.

```
  data want;
    array prices (0:11) _temporary_; * ring array, index is addressed in modulo;

    set have;
    by item;

    if first.item then do;
      call missing (of prices(*));
      ringdex = 0;
    end;

    format item_max_avg_price_12wk_prior dollar6.2;
    item_max_avg_price_12wk_prior = max (of prices(*));

* log ring array if interested;    
*    put item_max_avg_price_12wk_prior @;
*    do _n_ =lbound(prices) to hbound(prices); put prices(_n_) 6.2 @; end; put;

    prices(mod(ringdex,12)) = avg_price;  * modulo index <==> ring;

    ringdex++1;
  run;
```